# How to change edgecolor according to value of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I want to plot a Seaborn swarmplot of 'LapTimeSeconds' vs 'Driver' and I would like each swarm (driver) to be plotted in the corresponding colour in the 'Colour' column, I would also like for the edge colour of each of the markers to be the given 'Compound_colour'

I have a dataframe, df, looking like:

```
Driver   Colour  LapNumber   LapTimeSeconds   Compound   Compound_colour
HAM    #00d2be       2          91.647      MEDIUM         #ffd300
HAM    #00d2be       5          91.261      MEDIUM         #ffd300
HAM    #00d2be       8          91.082        SOFT         #FF3333
VER    #0600ef       3          91.842      MEDIUM         #ffd300
VER    #0600ef       6          91.906      MEDIUM         #ffd300
NOR    #ff8700       10         90.942        SOFT         #FF3333
```

Here is some code that I have currently.

```
sns.set_palette(df['Colour'].unique().tolist())

ax = sns.boxplot(x="Driver", y="LapTimeSeconds", data=df, width = 0.8, color = 'white')

ax = sns.swarmplot(x="Driver", y="LapTimeSeconds", data=df,  size = 9, linewidth=1)
```

which gives a plot looking like this plot

[image: plot]

However, I would like the edgecolor of each marker to be the corresponding 'Compound_colour', for example where the compound is 'medium' I want the edgecolor to be '#ffd300' (yellow) and where the compound is 'soft' I want the edgecolor to be '#FF3333' (red) .

This is similar to what I am aiming for. Is there a way to do this?

[image]

Comment: Does this help? [Is it possible to assign a colourmap for edgecolors in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33930784/7758804) and see [code and plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTqHu.png)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This method works well for plt.scatter, however when larger datasets are used scatter plots can get messy which is why I would like to use a swarmplot. I haven't managed to adapt this to a swarmplot yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To customize each marker in swarmplot, set the specified color as it can be obtained from the collection. Also, to change the color of each boxplot, change the color of the line object since it is contained in ax.artists.

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import colors

sns.set_palette(df['Colour'].unique().tolist())
fig,ax = plt.subplots()

ax =sns.boxplot(x="Driver", y="LapTimeSeconds", data=df, width=0.8, color='white')
swarm = sns.swarmplot(x="Driver", y="LapTimeSeconds", data=df, size=9, linewidth=1)

swarm.collections[0].set_ec(colors.to_rgba('#ffd300', 1.0))
swarm.collections[1].set_ec(colors.to_rgba('#FF3333', 1.0))
swarm.collections[2].set_ec(colors.to_rgba('#FF3333', 1.0))
swarm.collections[0].set_edgecolors(['#FF3333','#ffd300','#ffd300'])

colors = ['#00d2be','#0600ef','#ff8700']

for i, artist in enumerate(ax.artists):
    # print(i, artist)
    artist.set_edgecolor(colors[i])
    for j in range(i*6,i*6+6):
        line = ax.lines[j]
        line.set_color(colors[i])
        line.set_mfc(colors[i])
        line.set_mec(colors[i])

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response, unfortunately this isn't quite what I was looking for. In this example, the edgecolor is set to one specific value per swarm. However I would like several values per swarm, e.g. for 'HAM'  the 'Compound_colour' has values of '#ffd300, #ffd300, #FF3333'. Is there a way to simply implement this?

Comment: In `swarm.collections`, the drawn markers are stored, so if you want to give each of them a different color, you can do so by specifying any color. The answer code and graphs have been updated.